# Creating custom Model for face recognition error while running

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, artificial-intelligence

I keep getting this error my YAML model file is :

```
`nc: 7  # number of classes
scales:
  n: [0.33, 0.25, 1024]

# ResNet-like backbone
backbone:
  - [-1, 1, ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv, [3, 16, 7, 2]]  # 0-Initial convolution
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d, [16]]  # Use torch.nn.BatchNorm2d for batch normalization
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.ReLU, [True]]  # Use torch.nn.ReLU for ReLU activation
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.MaxPool2d, [3, 2]]  # 1-Pool
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.Conv2d, [16, 64, 3, 2, 1]]  # 2-Convolutional layer
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d, [64]]  # Use torch.nn.BatchNorm2d for batch normalization
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.ReLU, [True]]  # Use torch.nn.ReLU for ReLU activation
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.Conv2d, [64, 128, 3, 2, 1]]  # 3-Convolutional layer
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d, [128]]  # Use torch.nn.BatchNorm2d for batch normalization
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.ReLU, [True]]  # Use torch.nn.ReLU for ReLU activation
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.Conv2d, [128, 256, 3, 2, 1]]  # 4-Convolutional layer

# Modified head for feature extraction and classification
head:
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d, [1]]  # Replace Upsample with AdaptiveAvgPool2d
  - [-1, 1, Flatten, []]
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.Linear, [256, 512]]  # Modify fully connected layer for feature extraction
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.ReLU, [True]]  # Use torch.nn.ReLU for ReLU activation
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.Linear, [512, nc]]  # Modify fully connected layer for classification
  - [-1, 1, torch.nn.BatchNorm1d, [nc]]  # Apply batch normalization to the embeddings
  - [-1, 1, TripletLoss, [0.2]]  # Use TripletLoss with margin 0.2

  - [[5], 1, Detect, [nc]]  # Detect(ResNet layers) - Update detection layer

# Adjust input size
input_size: [224, 224]  # Adjust according to your desired input size
```

`

and my code is

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("TESTMODEL.yaml")  # build a YOLOv8n model from scratch
# YOLO("model.pt")  use pre-trained model if available
model.info()  # display model information
model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=1)  # train the model
```

the error:

```
WARNING  no model scale passed. Assuming scale='n'.

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments
  0                  -1  1      2384  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 7, 2]
  1                  -1  1        32  torch.nn.modules.batchnorm.BatchNorm2d       [16]
  2                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.activation.ReLU             [True]
  3                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.pooling.MaxPool2d           [3, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\from ultralytics import YOLO.py", line 3, in <module>
    model = YOLO("TESTMODEL.yaml")  # build a YOLOv8n model from scratch
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\model.py", line 105, in __init__
    self._new(model, task)
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\model.py", line 138, in _new    
    self.model = TASK_MAP[self.task][0](cfg_dict, verbose=verbose and RANK == -1)  # build model
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py", line 233, in __init__
    self.model, self.save = parse_model(deepcopy(self.yaml), ch=ch, verbose=verbose)  # model, savelist
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py", line 628, in parse_model
    m = getattr(torch.nn, m[3:]) if 'nn.' in m else globals()[m]  # get module
KeyError: 'torchvision.models.resnet.ResNet'
```

how can I fix the model I want it to be mixture of yolov8 model and adding layer to run face recognition and it can extract features of faces how can I do that so I can start training my data I would appreciate the help

I want to know what is wrong with my model and help to adjust it  or if there any resources that can be found